# How to make a CDF from a histogram in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, statistics, histogram, probability, cdf

I am trying to create function that takes a histogram and makes a CDF from it.
However I cannot use the `cdfplot` function in Matlab.

How would I go about doing this?

This produces the input histogram:

```
x = randn(1000,1);
nbins = 25;
h = histogram(x,nbins)
```

Answer (score 3):

The most straightforward way to create a cumulative distribution from data is to generate an [empirical CDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_distribution_function). The [`ecdf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/ecdf.html) can do this directly. By default, this doesn't require one to produce a histogram for a dataset:

```
x = randn(1000,1);
ecdf(x);
```

[image: Empirical CDF]

However, if you want a lower resolution CDF, you can use `histogram` directly with the [`'cdf'` normalization](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histogram.html#input_argument_namevalue_normalization) option:

```
x = randn(1000,1);
nbins = 25;
histogram(x,nbins,'Normalization','cdf');
```

[image: CDF histogram option]

You might find the `'cumcount'` option useful too. See the documentation for `ecdf` and [`histogram`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histogram.html) for details on how to extract and use the output from these functions.

Answer (score 2):

Use MATLAB's cumsum function, after normalizing the histogram.

```
hNormalized = h.Values / sum(h.Values);
cdf = cumsum(hNormalized)
```

The full code:

```
x = randn(1000,1);
nbins = 25;
h = histogram(x,nbins);
hNormalized = h.Values / sum(h.Values);
cdf = cumsum(hNormalized);
```

Results with smaller nBins (nBins = 8):

```
hNormalized =

0.0210    0.0770    0.1930    0.2830    0.2580    0.1250    0.0370    0.0060

cdf =

0.0210    0.0980    0.2910    0.5740    0.8320    0.9570    0.9940    1.0000
```

Comment: i keep getting this error "CUMSUM supports only numerical or logical inputs.
"

Comment: The reason: the name of the MATLAB's function which calculates histogram is called "hist" and not "historgam".
I will supply the full code.

Comment: Also, don't forget to normalize your histogram.

Comment: No, [`histogram`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histogram.html) is the name of the function. [`hist`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hist.html?refresh=true) has been deprecated for a few years now (with a fairly strong suggestion to no longer use it). `histogram` returns a struct where `h.Values` is equivalent to what `hist` returns.

Comment: @horchler I didn't know that. Thank you for your comment, I updated my answer accordingly.